# How to Parsing Android JsonObject and storing it after storing the Object with JsonArray inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I was trying to parse a `Json` like the following:

```
     {
      "status": "ok",
      "feed": {
        "title": "title1",
        "link": "http://www.link/",
        "author": "",
        "description": "desc",
        "image": ""
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "something",
          "link": "something",
          "guid": "something",
          "pubDate": "date",
          "categories": [],
          "author": "",
          "thumbnail": "",
          "description": null,
          "content": null
        },
...
...
```

And i'm getting the expected results from `response` but, that's not the point.Here is what i did:

```
try {

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject feed_object = response.getJSONObject("feed");
            PostItems item = new PostItems();
            item.setAuthor(feed_object.getString("title"));

            JSONArray items_arr = response.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < items_arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = items_arr.getJSONObject(i);

                item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                item.setDate(post.getString("pubDate")); // As expected results

                feedItem.add(item);
            }

        }
```

The point is, if i store the (**first `object`**) *like what i did so far as above codes*, the `RecyclerView` is showing the items but without setting the correct `title` and `date` inside the items.

**And if i store it inside the array and after that, setting one inside the array(for `array`) and outside the `array`, it's just showing an error like this:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
               at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
               at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:449)
               at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:136)
               at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:99)
               at client.com.news.RecyclerViews.MainSanjeshRecyclerView.MyRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter.java:34)
               at client.com.news.RecyclerViews.MainSanjeshRecyclerView.MyRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter.java:14)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5465)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5498)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4735)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4611)
               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903)
               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1684)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
               at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
               at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1139)
               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
            at android.vi
```

**The second try:**

```
try {

                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONObject feed_object = response.getJSONObject("feed");
                PostItems item = new PostItems();
                item.setAuthor(feed_object.getString("title"));

                JSONArray items_arr = response.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < items_arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = items_arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    PostItems item2 = new PostItems();
                    item2.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                    item2.setDate(post.getString("pubDate"));

                    feedItem.add(item2);
                }
                feedItem.add(item);
            }
```

Actually, i've tried anything you can even imagine it and saw any questions on stackoverflow and i couldn't find something like this questiion, but one time, just showing one item without correct data from object and one time without showing the correct datas from that `Array`.

Any helps would be great.

Comment: what's a line `MyRecyclerAdapter.java:34` ?

Comment: this is it, `feedListRowHolder.author.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getAuthor()));` but i think that's not the point, this is only happening when i'm trying to set this line twice llike the second codes: `feedItem.add(item2);
feedItem.add(item);`

Comment: `getAuthor` is returning null. Note at side:  
`PostItems item = new PostItems();` should be instantiated at every itetration of the for loop – Blackbelt just now   edit

Comment: I thought so, but keep showing the above results(error)

Comment: you are not parsing author anywhere in your code. Why do you expect, getAuthor to return something != null?

Comment: Sorry i missed the actual json, the first author that i'm trying to parse is not inside the array.updated the question, please check the actual json

Comment: `item.setAuthor(post.optString("author"), "");` in the for loop. `item2.setAuthor(feed_item.optString("author"), "");` outside the for loop. So

Comment: Actually i thought if we are using/parsing the first object, we can't use the codes inside that array but `Rohit5k2` answered the question and the point was in storing the datas inside the array but with that first object, interesting, never think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `getAuthor()` in every item when clearly it was set for only one (first) item in the `ArrayList`. When it doesn't have any value it return `null`, resulting `NullPointerException`. Also new object should be created at every iteration.

Just move

```
PostItems item = new PostItems();
item.setAuthor(feed_object.getString("title"));
```

inside `for` loop.

**Edit**

```
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

    JSONObject feed_object = response.getJSONObject("feed");

    JSONArray items_arr = response.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < items_arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject post = items_arr.getJSONObject(i);
        PostItems item = new PostItems();
        item.setAuthor(feed_object.getString("title")); // being fetched from top node
        item.setTitle(post.getString("title")); // being fetched from array
        item.setDate(post.getString("pubDate")); // being fetched from array

        feedItem.add(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work, that's not what i'm talking about actually, read the comments please.

Comment: Please match your code with mine. Just try this code.

Comment: Great, so the point was in using those codes inside each loop, never think about it

Comment: Never think about it, of course :), i was working on it about a day! thanks